# JTransform FFT returning infinity

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to get the fft data of a wav file in java using JTransforms. I read the wav file as Double. When I perform realforward() from JTRansforms on the data almost all of the returned data that I get is infinity. Also the few values that are not infinity are very high around 10^100 or more. When I perform fft on the same data on Python I get proper results.

Also I notices something strange. When I read the data from wav file as type long they are different from when I read them as double in java. Infact, reading the same file as double in java, and reading the same file in python returns different data. However, when I reading a wav file as long in java and reading the same file in python return similar data. What can I do to get proper fft results.

Here is my code

```
        //Read File
        WavFile file = WavFile.openWavFile(new File( "Samples Set/Voice6T.wav" ) );
        file.display();

        ArrayList<ArrayList <Double>> samples = new ArrayList< ArrayList <Double>>();

        //Create Hanning Window
        ArrayList<Double> hann = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= fsize; i++ )
        {
            hann.add( 0.5d * ( 1d - (double) Math.cos( ( TWO_PI * i) / ( fsize - 1 )) ) );
        }

        //Here I divide data into 50% overlapping frames of length 256. fsize = 256
        //Also I multiply hanning window. Every frame is added to samples.
        ArrayList<Double> prev = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int len;

        {
            double f_half[] = new double[fsize/2];
            double s_half[] = new double [fsize/2];

            len = file.readFrames( f_half, fsize/2);
            len = file.readFrames( s_half, fsize/2);

            ArrayList<Double> fh = new ArrayList<Double>( Arrays.asList( Arrays.stream(f_half).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new) ) );
            prev = new ArrayList<Double>( Arrays.asList( Arrays.stream(s_half).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new) ) );

            fh.addAll(prev);

            ArrayList<Double> temp = (ArrayList<Double>) IntStream.range(0, hann.size())
                     .mapToObj(i -> fh.get(i) * hann.get(i))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

            samples.add(temp);
        }

        //I continue the above process in a loop.
        do
        {
            double f_half[] = new double[fsize/2];
            len = file.readFrames( f_half, fsize/2);
            if (len != fsize/2) break;

            ArrayList<Double> fh = new ArrayList<Double>( Arrays.asList( Arrays.stream(f_half).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new) ) );

            prev.addAll(fh);
            ArrayList<Double> t1 = prev;
            prev = fh;

            ArrayList<Double> temp = (ArrayList<Double>) IntStream.range(0, hann.size())
                     .mapToObj(i -> t1.get(i) * hann.get(i))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
            samples.add(temp);
        }
        while( len != 0 );

        //Next I perform FFT.
        DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D( samples.get(0).size() );
        double fft_data[] = new double[ samples.get(0).size() ];

        for ( int i = 0; i < samples.size(); i++ )
        {
            System.arraycopy( ArrayUtils.toPrimitive( samples.get(i).toArray( new Double[samples.get(i).size()] ) ),
                    0, fft_data, 0, samples.get(0).size() );
            fft.realForward(fft_data);

            ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for ( int j = 0; j < fft_data.length; j = j + 2 )
            {
                temp.add( Math.sqrt( (fft_data[j]*fft_data[j]) + (fft_data[j+1]*fft_data[j+1]) ) );
            }
            //Most of the data in fft_data and temp is Infinity.
            samples.set(i, temp);               
        }
```

Comment: Since it looks like you're having issues with reading the wav file, perhaps you could focus your question on that aspect, and provide more details about the `WavFile` implementation you are using as well as the audio sample you are using (e.g. sampling rate, bytes per samples, number of channels, encoding format, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. I was able to solve the issue completely. It was a silly mistake in the code. Every time data was transformed it replaced its time domain equivalent in samples and its size is 512.The line of code which copies time domain data to buffer for fft was took the size parameter of frame 0 which was first to be transformed instead of taking the size of the frame currently being processed. This caused all the trouble.